# Моргание окна при первом показе

Tags: wpf

Есть окно с Canvas, у Canvas в качестве фона используется изображение. При первом показе окно "моргает", т.е. сначала рисуется окно с белым фоном, а только потом с изображением. Как это исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: Без кода вопрос не ясен. Кто знает, может, вы изображение грузите из сети? Давайте **минимальный** код, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Сталкивался с подобным, правда в windows form, помогало включить двойной буфер для окна. Возможно в wpf это свойство у формы также присутствует и поможет.

Comment: Тут дело не в долгой загрузке изображения, а в том что сначала окно рисуется с белым фоном, а уже потом с фоном изображения. Я тоже помню что на windowsforms какое то свойство менял для этого, а вот какое не помню.

Comment: @Proleer: Код! Код! Нам нужен код, без него можно только гадать на кофейной гуще.

Причём пожалуйста минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Вот код демонстрирующий проблему:
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"  WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</Window>

В реальном приложении изображение берется заранее со всего экрана.

Comment: Нашел такой кусочек кода:

windowBackground.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize; //обязательно должно быть, решает одну проблему

Как оказалось решает мою проблему. Ура!